# Chrome extension- creating a javascript XMLHttpRequest at a function that is called back on 'onclick'

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, contextmenu, google-chrome-extension

I have the following question:
I am trying to write a javascript code for a chrome extension that uses context menus.

```
var id = chrome.contextMenus.create({"title": "search Flickr", "contexts":"selection","onclick":searchSelection});

function searchSelection(info,tab){
var xhReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
 xhReq.open("GET", "sumGet.phtml?figure1=5&figure2=10", false);
 xhReq.send(null);
 var serverResponse = xhReq.responseText;
 alert(serverResponse); // Shows "15"

}
```

as you can see I am trying to create an http request at this function. for some reason this doesn't work.
what is wrong?
Thanks,
Mary

Comment: What doesn't work? Your alert shows `15`, is that incorrect? And don't use a synchronous `XMLHttpRequest`, but an asynchronous one (use `true` as third parameter to `xhReq.open`) and use a callback handler.

Comment: changed it to true, now it sends an empty alert with no content, what do you mean to use a callback handler? the original code sends an http request to flickr search photo.

Comment: Do you get an exception, like the one that states that protocols and domains do not match?

Answer (score 1):

It's always better to use an asynchronous `XMLHttpRequest`, a synchronous call will block the browser, which might lead to a bad user experience.

With an asynchronous request you'll have to use a callback handler, because without it you won't be able to get the `responseText`. Does it work when you do something like this:

```
function searchSelection(info,tab){
    var xhReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhReq.open("GET", "sumGet.phtml?figure1=5&figure2=10", true);
    xhReq.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhReq.readyState == 4) {
            if (xhReq.status == 200) {
                var serverResponse = xhReq.responseText;
                alert(serverResponse); // Shows "15"
            }
        }
    };
    xhReq.send();
}
```